# get single row from table with join on second table and show it in details view

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, join, model

I have aTable where one component is carID and in bTable
there are carNames.
Now I have aTables id.
in controller in default way we do like this

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
var aObject= db.aTable.Find(id);
return View(aObject);
```

and we generate "details" view using aTable model class.

but in that case I will have view where I will show only id of car not name.
And I want to join bTable while querying aTable and in view I want to show car Name text.

For that I must create new model class. I've done it. but how do I perform single object query with join using entity framework and transfer object to view ?

```
    a table is 
   int aID
   string aName
   int carID

    b talbe is
   int bID
   string bcarName


 public class ModifiedaTableModel
{
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "aIDis required.")]
        public int aID{ get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "aName required.")]
        public string aName{ get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "carName required.")]
        public string carName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you plz show your `aTable`, `bTable` and `ViewModel` class?

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: did u successfully apply relation between both aTable and bTable means in `bID` in bTable is primary key and `carID` in aTable is foreign key

Comment: How that two tables relate to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `CarID` is `bID`, do:

```
var modifiedATableModel = (from a in aTable
                          join b in bTable
                          on a.carID equals b.bID
                          select new ModifiedaTableModel
                          {
                              aID = a.aID,
                              aName = a.aName,
                              carName = b.bcarName
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I've done it and got this error while trying going to view : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[project.Models.modifiedATableModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'project.Models.modifiedATableModel'.

Comment: What is the type of your model in view?

Comment: @model project.Models.modifiedATableModel

Comment: It is single result, are you assuming that this join will return single result?

Answer (score 0):

check this article [linq101Samples](https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/join/Join)

**Opt 1**

```
 var query = db.aTable
               .Join(db.bTable, r => r.aID, 
                                p => p.bID, 
             (r,p) => new ModifiedaTableModel 
                      {
                         aID = r.aID,
                         aName = r.aName,
                         carName = p.carName
                      }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i considered your successfully satisfied relation between both of `aTable` and `bTable` and project your query result to `ModifiedaTableModel` by joining both of table.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    ModifiedaTableModel model = new ModifiedaTableModel();
    if (id != null)
    {
        model = (from a in db.aTable
                 join b in db.bTable on a.carID equals b.bID
                 where a.aID == id.Value
                 select new ModifiedaTableModel
                 {
                     aID = a.aID,
                     aName = a.aName,
                     carName = b.bcarName
                 }).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(model);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @David, view the answer might be it help you :)